# Returning multiple values using Vlookup in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet set up to automatically calculate meetings per day by day of the week.  I would like to write a formula to return all dates I have a meeting scheduled (comma separated preferably), but I am having some difficulty.  Using Vlookup, I can only get it to return the first date.

For example, here is what my data looks like:

```
         A                                 B                            C
 Initial Meetings          Follow-up Meetings            Date
         1                                1                       7/29/2015
         0                                1                       7/30/2015
         1                                1                       7/31/2015
         0                                0                       8/1/2015
         0                                0                       8/2/2015
```

I would like to write a formula to return "7/29/2015, 7/31/2015" in one cell, and "7/29/2015, 7/30/2015, 7/31/2015" in another, but I seem to be stuck.

Comment: This will be tough to do in a way the scales well with formulas. The primary bottleneck is the limitations that concatenate has. Otherwise you could extract your values into an area and then concatenate with a delimiter. You have added the `excel-vba` tag but only mention a formula. Are you open to using VBA for this purpose?

Comment: You could do two separate columns (one for initial, one for followup) with =IF((meeting column) <> 0, date, ), then do advanced filter and get the uniques from both of those columns to have easily accessible lists, but VBA would be your friend here.

Comment: I'm definitely open to using VBA!  I just was not sure if it could be done with formulas.  I'm fairly new to VBA, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with vLookup.

This can be done relatively easily in a VB script, but it would affect portability as many if not most users disable macros by default and in many cases users are prevented from using Macros because their company disables them and makes it policy that users should not use them.

If you are OK with Macros, you can put the following into a *new module* and then use `=MultiVlookup(lookup_value,table_array, col_index_num)` in the same way as you'd use vlookup and it should give you a comma separated list of multiple matches:

```
Public Function MultiVlookup(find_value, search_range, return_row)
  Dim myval ' String to represent return value (comma-separated list)
  Dim comma ' Bool to represent whether we need to prefix the next result with ", "
  comma = False
  'Debug.Print find_value.value, return_row
  For Each rw In search_range.Rows ' Iterate through each row in the range
    If rw.Cells(1, 1).value = find_value Then ' If we have found the lookup value...
      If comma Then  ' Add a comma if it's not the first value we're adding to the list
        myval = myval + ", "
      Else
        comma = True
      End If
      myval = myval + Str(rw.Cells(1, return_row).value)
    End If
  Next
  MultiVlookup = myval
End Function
```

This may not be the cleanest way of doing it, and it isn't a direct copy of vlookup (for instance it does not have a fourth "range lookup" argument as vlookup does), but it works for my test:

[image]

Finally my original suggestion (in case it helps others - it's not the exact solution to the question) was:

I've not tried it myself, but [this link](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119:vlookup-multiple-values-return-multiple-corresponding-values-for-one-lookup-value&catid=77&Itemid=473) shows what I think you might be looking for.

Comment: The solution linked outputs as an array or a sum of values. You would need intermediary columns to then join on a final cell. Doesn't seem exactly what OP was requesting.

Comment: I've tried the technique described in your link, but for some reason it's not working for my data.  I'm not concerned about portability as this spreadsheet is only for me.  Do you have any tips on how this could be done using VBA?

Comment: If you are willing, I would absolutely appreciate any help! Portability is definitely not an issue for me at all, nor is macro security, as I do not plan to share this sheet with anyone.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more appropriate solution (I've left the other link that wasn't quite what you wanted at the bottom of the page in case it's useful to others)

Comment: Thank you so much SteJ - This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help - any chance of an "accepted answer"?

Answer (score 0):

Great code, but don't forget to add the following is you use Option Explicit:

```
Dim rw As Range
```

WHEELS

Comment: This looks more like a comment to another answer rather than a new answer.