# Need to concatenate data in a column based on another column after filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, concatenation

Need to have a result like below based on input from the tow columns. Any ideas folks ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIndU.png)

example. I filter data "A" in column 1, I might get one or more lines in column 2. i needs to concatenate all details in column 2 against the data "A"

Comment: What Excel version are you using?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710361/returning-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods if you have Excel 2016 it is a new function called `TEXTJOIN`

```
=TEXTJOIN(Delimiter, False to concatenate spaces - True without spaces, Range to concatenate)
```

For your case you will need to use an nested `IF`:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(Range Criteria = Criteria,Range to Concatenate,""))}
```

To activate the function use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

The second method is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174457/excel-vba-code-for-concatenating-data-in-multiple-columns-and-removing-duplicate/48178720#48178720) in case you don't have Excel 2016. It was a similar question that I answered using **Power Query**.

I Made this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/iolvOPdS4SY). It is in Spanish but I am using the English Excel version.