# Excel VBA Code for concatenating data in multiple columns and removing duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Example Photo]

In reference to the attached "Example Photo" Image...

I would like to concatenate the unique data in Columns I and K into one cell (separated by line break) and remove the duplicated information in the other columns. My goal is to have the data look like rows 2 and 7 without the duplicated rows in between.

Comment: You need to have a go yourself first and come back with any difficulties.  A pointer may be to try an array formula and conditional formatting as believe you can achieve using them

Comment: Would values in Column A suffice for determining uniqueness? Please note that value in `Cell J2` is different to the ones in `Cells J3 to J6`.

Comment: Yes, values in Column A would suffice for determining uniqueness. If there is a value in cells J2-J6, there will only be one value, but it won't necessarily be listed in the first row as it is in my example. So it might make sense to concatenate that column as well even though there will only be one value if any in the group of duplicates from column A.

Comment: -Nathan_Sav : I am not trying to achieve anything with conditional formatting. My picture has certain things highlighted to draw attention to what i am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can download **Power Query** or if you have Excel 2016 it is a default its name is **Get & Tranform** in the **Data** Tab.

1. Select any cell in your main table.
2. Go to **Power Query** or **Data** and select **From Table/Range**.
3. It will be a box with the range **OK**.

It will open the Query Editor

4. Go to **Home** select **Group by**.
5. In the Options:

   - **Group by:** Add all the fields you don't want to concatenate.
   - **New Column name:** It could be "Group".
   - **Operation:** Select All Rows.
   - **OK**.
6. Go to **Add Column** select **Custom Columna**.
7. Concatenate field Name

   `[Column Named Step 5][Column Name where is the data to concatenate]`
8. Go to the new field and click in the right corner (Arrows) and select **Extract Values...**.
9. Select delimiter `#(lf)` **OK**.
10. Go to **Home** tab and select **Advanced Editor**.
11. There look for `""#(lf)""` and delete the extra `""` it should be `"#(lf)"` click in **Done**.
12. Got **Home** select **Close & Load**.

It will create a new sheet with a table with your new data.

11. Use **Wrap Text** in **Home** tab to see the lines break.

You can append more data in the main table and it will be just a right click refresh in the Power Query Table and you will get your data.

I made this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/iolvOPdS4SY). It is in Spanish but I am using the English Excel version.